# Excel show drop-down list based on the value of the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97ziu.png), 
I have a list of red coloured fruits, and a list below it, of yellow coloured fruits, as you can see.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23tiZ.png), I have two drop-down lists used to select colours and fruits.
When selecting "Red", in the drop-down list on the left, I would like the list on the right to show the list of red coloured fruits **only**. When selecting "Yellow", in the drop-down list on the left, I would like the list on the right to show the list of yellow coloured fruits **only**.
What kind of formula do I use to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a formula like this.  The red fruit is listed in column AA.
The yellow fruit is listed in column AB.
`=IF(A1="Red",OFFSET(AA2,0,0,COUNTA(AA2:AA10),1),IF(A1="Yellow",OFFSET(AB2,0,0,COUNTA(AB2:AB10),1)))`

In the data validation list for the cell to select the fruit input that formula above.

**How it works**

The IF statement evaluates the color of the fruit selected.  The OFFSET command will create a list starting at the top of the selected color fruit list.  The COUNTA formula counts the number of fruit in the column (up to 10 fruit).

Comment: I don't know how to use the `offset` function.
Can you explain step-by-step what do I do, please?
Thanks :)

Comment: Got it working, you're super awesome! Thanks a lot!
Marked as accepted answer!

Comment: But the formula is confusing, like if I wanted instead of having red fruit in column `AA`, I wanted it in column `AM` for example, how do I do that?
I tried changing the `AA` to `AM` normally, but it caused an error, that's why I'm asking.